# Regex expression finding digits from a string

Tags: regex

I have the following string which I need to get the number '4' from the string to use it for further use in the code:

```
   1 IDM  485556     4     427   RUN  0 ===== Not set =====  unknown
```

It occurs twice in the string but both conveys the same message. Please can someone help me with an easy way to search for that digit using python regex

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: I think I figure it output as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Hello find the following regex to the above string:

```
\s{3}\d\s\w{3}\s+\d+\s+(\d)\s+
```